# Prevent Google Music (but not other players!) from scanning local files

Tags: google-play-music, media-player, media-files, mp3, media-scanner

I'm wondering if there exist other options rather than adding  the '.nomedia' file - this way I'm hiding the mp3s for all the players I have. But I want just Google Music not to see them, not other ones.

BTW, placing a dot in the beginning of the folder name hides the files in all the players as well.

Comment: You can't... Apps that are following the Android guidelines do not scan the media themselves, but use the common android.provider.MediaStore sqlite database of the operating system, meaning all media players following the Android guidelines will use the same database. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are on android 6 and above, you can just revoke "Storage Permission" of the application.

[image: Steps to revoke "Storage Permission" of a given application]

Comment: As the questioner probably doesn't know how to do that, it might be useful to explain how.

Comment: But Google Play Music cannot work without such a permission - it needs to cache the music on the device... It's a pity I cannot deny the permission to the SD card solely.